# Constrain height of combo box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box within a panel within a ToolStripControlHost, I know that I probably shouldn't be using ToolStrip related classes outside of a ToolStrip but I couldn't find any other wait to make the control overlay other controls/windows. The issue that I have is that as more items get added to the combo box it ends up starting further and further up the screen, eventually I end up with the combo box going all the way from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen.

What I would like it to do is be able to expand downwards but not upwards, if it runs out of room then it should scroll. I've attempted to do this by wrapping it in a Panel with AutoScroll= true. I set the height of the Panel every time an item is added to the combo box like this:

```
var screenY = PointToScreen(_pnlListBoxContainer.Location).Y;
var newBottom = _listBox.Height + screenY;
if (newBottom > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
{
    _pnlListBoxContainer.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - screenY;
}
else
{
    _pnlListBoxContainer.Height = newBottom;
}
_pnlListBoxContainer.MaximumSize = _pnlListBoxContainer.Size;
```

I'm quite new to winforms and I'm not sure if this should work or if there is a better way of doing it, currently it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Joe

P.S. The full (very messy and hacked together) code is here - sorry:

```
public class AutoCompleteTextBox : TransparentTextboxWithBorder
{
    private ToolStripDropDown _popupControl;
    private ToolStripControlHost _controlHost;
    private Panel _pnlListBoxContainer;
    private ListBox _listBox;
    private bool _isAdded;
    private IAutoCompletable[] _values;
    private String _formerValue = String.Empty;
    public Font ListBoxFont
    {
        get { return _listBox.Font; }
        set { _listBox.Font = value; }
    }

    public event AutoCompleteTextBoxItemSelectedEventHandler OnItemSelected;

    public void ItemSelected()
    {
        InsertWord((String)_listBox.SelectedItem);
        ResetListBox();
        _formerValue = this.Text;
        if (OnItemSelected != null)
        {
            var item = Values.First(v => v.DisplayText == (string)_listBox.SelectedItem);
            OnItemSelected(this, new AutoCompleteTextBoxItemSelectedEventArgs { SelectedItem = item });
        }
    }

    public AutoCompleteTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResetListBox();

    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        _listBox = new ListBox();
        _pnlListBoxContainer = new Panel { BackColor = Color.Red, Width = 100, Height = 400,AutoScroll = true};
        _pnlListBoxContainer.MinimumSize = _pnlListBoxContainer.Size;
        _pnlListBoxContainer.Controls.Add(_listBox);
        _popupControl = new ToolStripDropDown();
        _popupControl.Padding = new Padding(0);
        _popupControl.Margin = new Padding(0);
        _popupControl.AutoClose = false; // Focus bug - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b8f9cf48-9bd4-4e8e-a9b7-bedc7491c619/toolstripcontrolhost-focus-problem?forum=winforms
        _popupControl.AutoSize = true;
        //_controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(_listBox);
        _controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(_pnlListBoxContainer);
        _controlHost.Padding = new Padding(0);
        _controlHost.Margin = new Padding(0);

        _popupControl.Items.Add(_controlHost);
        _listBox.IntegralHeight = true;
        _listBox.MouseDown += _listBox_Click;
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.this_KeyDown);
        this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.this_KeyUp);
        this.LostFocus += AutoCompleteTextBox_LostFocus;


        // Fixed by AutoClose = false above
        // List box is now completly seperate so it needs its own key handlers
        //_controlHost.KeyDown +=  new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.this_KeyDown);
        //_controlHost.KeyUp += (sender, args) =>
        //{
        //    if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        //    {
        //        // For some reason the key down event doesnt fire for tab when in a controlhost so we just use key up
        //        this_KeyDown(sender, args);
        //    }
        //    this_KeyUp(sender, args);
        //};

    }

    void AutoCompleteTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Firing close means that the selected index changed event doesn't fire so we delay it
        var tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 100;
        tmr.Tick += (o, args) =>
        {
            _popupControl.Close();
            tmr.Stop();
        };
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void _listBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemSelected();
    }

    private void ShowListBox()
    {
        if (!_isAdded)
        {
            //_listBox.Left = this.Left;
            //_listBox.Top = this.Top + this.Height;
            //_pnlListBoxContainer.Left = this.Left;
            //_pnlListBoxContainer.Top = this.Top + this.Height;
            _isAdded = true;
        }
        //_listBox.Visible = true;
        //_listBox.BringToFront();
        _pnlListBoxContainer.Visible = true;
        _pnlListBoxContainer.BringToFront();
        _popupControl.BackColor = Color.Green;
        _popupControl.Show(this, CalculateDropPosition(), ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
    }

    private Point CalculateDropPosition()
    {
        Point point = new Point(0, this.Height);
        if ((this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).Y + this.Height + _controlHost.Height) > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height)
        {
            point.Y = -this._controlHost.Height - 7;
        }
        return point;
    }

    public void ResetListBox()
    {
        _popupControl.Close();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        ResetListBox();
        _formerValue = string.Empty;
        _oldMatchesHashCode = 0;
    }

    private void this_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateListBox();
    }

    private void this_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Return:
            case Keys.Tab:
                {
                    if (_listBox.Visible)
                    {
                        ItemSelected();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Down:
                {
                    if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex < _listBox.Items.Count - 1))
                    {
                        _listBox.SelectedIndex++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Up:
                {
                    if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex > 0))
                    {
                        _listBox.SelectedIndex--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Tab:
                return true;
            default:
                return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }

    private int _oldMatchesHashCode = 0;
    private void UpdateListBox()
    {
        if (this.Text != _formerValue)
        {
            _formerValue = this.Text;
            String word = GetWord();

            if (word.Length > 0)
            {
                var matches = Array.FindAll(_values,
                    x => (x.Match(word) && !SelectedValues.Contains(x.DisplayText)));
                int hashCode = 0;
                foreach (var match in matches)
                {
                    unchecked
                    {
                        hashCode += match.DisplayText.GetHashCode();
                    }
                }
                if (hashCode == _oldMatchesHashCode)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _oldMatchesHashCode = hashCode;
                if (matches.Length > 0)
                {
                    SuspendLayout();
                    ShowListBox();
                    _listBox.Items.Clear();
                    Array.ForEach(matches, x => _listBox.Items.Add(x.DisplayText));
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    _listBox.Height = 0;
                    _listBox.Width = 0;
                    this.Focus();
                    using (Graphics graphics = _listBox.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            _listBox.Height += _listBox.GetItemHeight(i);
                            // it item width is larger than the current one
                            // set it to the new max item width
                            // GetItemRectangle does not work for me
                            // we add a little extra space by using '_'
                            int itemWidth = (int)graphics.MeasureString(((String)_listBox.Items[i]) + "_", _listBox.Font).Width;
                            _listBox.Width = (_listBox.Width < itemWidth) ? itemWidth : _listBox.Width;
                        }
                    }

                    if (_listBox.Width < 200)
                        _listBox.Width = 200;
                    _pnlListBoxContainer.Width = _listBox.Width;

                    var screenY = PointToScreen(_pnlListBoxContainer.Location).Y;
                    var newBottom = _listBox.Height + screenY;
                    if (newBottom > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
                    {
                        _pnlListBoxContainer.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - screenY;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _pnlListBoxContainer.Height = newBottom;
                    }
                    _pnlListBoxContainer.MaximumSize = _pnlListBoxContainer.Size;

                    ResumeLayout();
                }
                else
                {
                    ResetListBox();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ResetListBox();
                _oldMatchesHashCode = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private String GetWord()
    {
        String text = this.Text;
        int pos = this.SelectionStart;

        int posStart = text.LastIndexOf(';', (pos < 1) ? 0 : pos - 1);
        posStart = (posStart == -1) ? 0 : posStart + 1;
        int posEnd = text.IndexOf(';', pos);
        posEnd = (posEnd == -1) ? text.Length : posEnd;

        int length = ((posEnd - posStart) < 0) ? 0 : posEnd - posStart;

        return text.Substring(posStart, length);
    }

    private void InsertWord(String newTag)
    {
        String text = this.Text;
        int pos = this.SelectionStart;

        int posStart = text.LastIndexOf(';', (pos < 1) ? 0 : pos - 1);
        posStart = (posStart == -1) ? 0 : posStart + 1;
        int posEnd = text.IndexOf(';', pos);

        String firstPart = text.Substring(0, posStart) + newTag;
        String updatedText = firstPart + ((posEnd == -1) ? "" : text.Substring(posEnd, text.Length - posEnd));


        this.Text = updatedText;
        this.SelectionStart = firstPart.Length;
    }

    public IAutoCompletable[] Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _values;
        }
        set
        {
            _values = value;
        }
    }

    public List<String> SelectedValues
    {
        get
        {
            String[] result = Text.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new List<String>(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean a combo box as in a dropdown menu, yes? If I'm understanding correctly, you're adding enough items to the combo box that it ends up being longer than your window when expanded?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out why:

Click your Combo Box, press F4 to open the Properties Window and set the `DropDownHeight` property to be 106 and set `MaxDropDownItems` to be 8. Those are the defaults for Combo boxes.